# Accessing a variable outside of a function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call a variable (var view) that it is defined in another function (func mapView).

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
   if annotation is MapSeismometerAnnotation{
     if let annotation = annotation as? MapSeismometerAnnotation{
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation,reuseIdentifier:annotation.identifier)
        ...
        ...
}
@IBAction func pressPlay(_ sender: Any){
    //I want to call here the variable view
}
```

My class is:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,SCSEarthquakesHandler,SCSPublicSeismometersHandler{
```

If I define the variable `var view: MKPinAnnotationView` under the class (outside the function), Xcode return me this error:

> Cannot override mutable property 'view' of type 'UIView?' with
> covariant type 'MKPinAnnotationView'

How can I solve this?

Comment: **I want to call a variable (var view)** please elaborate what is the problem - you can't call a variable inside a function

Comment: view is a property which is already defined in  UIViewController . So you must rename that var to some other name. And if you already declared a property {var view: MKPinAnnotationView} ,  then again adding var view will be resulting in a new local variable within the method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set another name

```
var otherName: MKPinAnnotationView
```

`view` variable name conflicts with the vc's `UIView` property

Answer (score 1):

View is not overridable because it is used by the `UIViewController`. Therefore you need to assign another name to the variable than `view`.

For example: `var annotationView: MKAnnotationView` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

view is already defined variable in UIViewController. Pick another name for your MKPinAnnotationView